# Custom attribute to apply to Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET Core 1.1 with VS.2017. I am using some custom attributes that I apply to objects like classes, structs, etc.

I was wondering if it is possible (and how) to "tag" a Razor view with one such custom attribute. I mean, those views are compiled so that probably means some sort of class is generated for each view.

Please concentrate on answering the question rather than questioning why I want to do it. There is a need -in my application- and therefore I seek a way to do it.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I also have this issue, would love some input on it